# Sonarqube scanner cannot resolve relative file path in PHPUnit coverage XML file

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When executing sonar-scanner with the example project available at:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/b0ebd45081e58c3cb7c660287d5ed7fb9c64bb17/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests

I get the following warning, and the coverage data is not sent to the Sonar host:

```
WARN: Could not resolve 1 file paths in phpunit.coverage.xml, first unresolved path: src/Math.php
```

Full output of command:

```
root@46e4a60694f9:/home/test/sonar-examples-master/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests# /home/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/test/sonar-examples-master/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
INFO: Java 1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.4.27-boot2docker amd64
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=240ms
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=24ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.1
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=141ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=55ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=141ms
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan PHP :: PHPUnit :: SonarQube Scanner
INFO: Language is forced to php
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=76ms
INFO: Base dir: /home/test/sonar-examples-master/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests
INFO: Working dir: /home/test/sonar-examples-master/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests/.sonar
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Test paths: tests
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en
INFO: Index files
INFO: 3 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for php: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=25ms
INFO: Sensor NoSonar Sensor
INFO: Sensor NoSonar Sensor (done) | time=65ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor PHP sensor
INFO: 2 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 2/2 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Analyzing PHPUnit test report: reports/phpunit.xml with org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitResultParser@31ddd4a4
INFO: Analyzing PHPUnit unit test coverage report: reports/phpunit.coverage.xml with PHPUnit Unit Test Coverage Result Parser
WARN: Could not resolve 1 file paths in phpunit.coverage.xml, first unresolved path: src/Math.php
INFO: No PHPUnit integration test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.itReportPath' property)
INFO: No PHPUnit overall coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.overallReportPath' property)
INFO: Sensor PHP sensor (done) | time=1419ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files (done) | time=11ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=49ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for php
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 2 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 96ms, dir size=27 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 18ms, zip size=13 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 115ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://***.elasticbeanstalk.com/dashboard/index/org.sonarqube:php-ut-sq-scanner
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://***.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/ce/task?id=AVhaEXKjVjsdBlz4sGdU
INFO: Task total time: 3.511 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 5.098s
INFO: Final Memory: 42M/149M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I change the path to absolute in the phpunit.coverage.xml, it seems to be working in Linux. On Windows docker quick start terminal (MINGW64) the only way to make it work is by using windows-style absolute paths:
C:\Users\username\projects\php-sonar-runner-unit-tests

**Is there any way to make it work with relative paths?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the README (on the same page that you linked):

> - In "reports/phpunit.coverage.xml", change the path "src/Math.php" to the full path of this file on your machine.

You must use the absolute path. It doesn't work with relative paths.

Note that this is just an example coverage report file, using one pre-generated by PHPUnit (also mentioned in the README). Normally you generate the coverage report file yourself before running SonarQube analysis, in which case it will have the correct absolute path in your system.

Comment: Thank you Janos. I completely missed that comment about changing the path.I am in fact using an own generated coverage file. However I run phpunit inside my docker container, so it generates linux-style paths. Sonar scanner however I run from the Windows host machine. In this case I guess I have no other option than to run a search and replace on the report file.

Comment: Can't you run sonar scanner in the docker container?

Comment: I could do that. Since it's a PHP project I didnt want to install Java in it. Today I tried another approach: I mapped the PHP files as volume into a Java-based sonar scanner container, and then it works quite well.

Comment: Cool, that sounds like a very good solution, given your environment.